# Replacing or deleting inlineshapes in a mail is working only once in Outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I programmed an outlook addin in vb.net which can save the mails in outlook 2010.
The user can decide to save the attachment with the mail or separate.

The addin works fine and saves the mails regardless the mail has an attachment or not.
The addin can save possible inlineshapes of the mail too.

But only one time.

If I save a mail with one or more inlineshape everything works fine (saving the inlineshape, replacing the inlineshape with text or deleting the inlineshape in the mail, saving the mail to disk).

After that, if I take another mail with an inlineshape, the saving works fine but the replacing or deleting of the inlineshape is not working.

Why that?
What I´m doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for all help.

This is the code which calls the function who saves the mail, attachments and inlineshapes:

```
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim outlookSel As Outlook.Selection

outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
outlookExp = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer
outlookSel = outlookExp.Selection 

For i As Integer = 1 To outlookSel.Count
   outlookObject = outlookSel.Item(i)
   SaveMail(outlookObject, onlyMails, strUser, strFormat, backupFolderMails, logFolder, bugFolder, indicator)
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(outlookObject)
   outlookObject = Nothing
   GC.Collect()
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
   GC.Collect()
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Next
```

Here is the code inside the "savemail" function which saves the inlineshape and replaces the inlineshape with text:

```
If GetSeparateAttachments() = True Then
   outlookAllAttachments = outlookObject.Attachments
   attachmentCounter = outlookAllAttachments.Count
   counter = 0
   While attachmentCounter <> counter
      outlookAttachment = outlookAllAttachments(attachmentCounter)
      If outlookAttachment.Type = Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olOLE Then
         If outlookObject.BodyFormat = 3 Then
            outlookInspector = outlookObject.GetInspector
            outlookWordEditor = outlookInspector.WordEditor
            If outlookWordEditor.ProtectionType <> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection Then
               outlookWordEditor.Unprotect()
            End If
            wordInlineShapes = outlookWordEditor.InlineShapes
            For j As Integer = wordInlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
               wordShape = wordInlineShapes.Item(j)
               wordShape.Select()
               outlookWordEditor.Application.Selection.CopyAsPicture()
               dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
               If dataObject.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
                  image = CType(dataObject.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), System.Drawing.Bitmap)
                  secureNameAttachment = CheckPath(GetDuplicateAttachments(), saveFolderAttachment & "\" & CheckFileName(mailTimestamp & "_" & outlookAttachment.DisplayName & j, replaceSign) & GetPictureFormat(image.RawFormat), fileExtension)
                  image.Save(secureNameAttachment)
                  attachmentsString = attachmentsString & ";" & secureNameAttachment
               Else
                  Throw New Exception("Error")
               End If
               wordRange = outlookWordEditor.Range(wordShape.Range.Characters.First.Start, wordShape.Range.Characters.Last.End)
               wordRange.Text = secureNameAttachment & vbCrLf
               System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordRange)
               wordRange = Nothing
               System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordShape)
               wordShape = Nothing
               counter = counter + 1
            Next
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordInlineShapes)
            wordInlineShapes = Nothing
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(outlookWordEditor)
            outlookWordEditor = Nothing
            outlookInspector.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olSave)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(outlookInspector)
            outlookInspector = Nothing
         Else
            Throw New Exception("Error")
         End If
      Else
         '
      End If
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(outlookAttachment)
      outlookAttachment = Nothing
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(outlookAllAttachments)
      outlookAllAttachments = Nothing
      outlookObject.Save()
   End While                        
End If
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far! eg: source code

Comment: Here is my code at the moment:

Comment: hugh? Please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I was at the wrong position.
Now the code is above.

Comment: Really, no one has an idea?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.